# Rails has_many and belongs_to on same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, factory-bot, minitest, stack-level

I have a School model that has_many :users.  But, each school also has a primary_user.  Here is my model:

```
 has_many :users
 belongs_to :primarycontact, :class_name => "User"
```

This works fine in my my production and dev app, but it raises stack level errors in FactoryGirl while testing.  The associations smell bad to me, and the stack level errors in testing indicate to me that there is probably a better way.

Is there a better way?  ...any ideas why FactoryGirl is struggling with it?

my factory

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :school do
      name "Test School"
      association :primarycontact, factory: :user, name: "Primary User"
    end
  end
```

Stack trace

```
  Userdoc
    test_0001_must be valid 0:00:09.143 ERROR
      stack level too deep
      Exception `SystemStackError' at:
```

So, the error is originating in a third model, Userdoc.  When the factory creates a Userdoc, it creates a User, .. the user must belong to a school so that factory also creates a School.  But, when the school factory gets triggered it also tries to create a user because of the primarycontact association.

Comment: I don't know about the problems with FactoryGirl, but in principle there is nothing wrong with this. You may want to post the test code that errors and the stack trace of the error itself.

Comment: I think what I need to do is not set a primary user in the User factory, but set it explicitly from other factories as needed. I added the info requested to the question.